Laptop fan makes rattling noise (see video)
My ASUS Vivobook pro 15 fan (one of two, the right one) starts making rattling noise after 40-60 minutes of use under above average load (https://streamable.com/q5fv75). Shaking and rotating the laptop in different directions fixes the issue for a short time, but then rattling starts again. Cleaning didn't help. Is replacing the fan the only viable option?

Likely, yes. Fans aren't typically too difficult to replace, even in laptops.

@music2myear yes but I can't replace the fan without removing the heat pipe, so I need to change thermal paste. And this thin laptop has too much to repaste that's weird (https://imgur.com/a/QvO3NVS). Anyway if I repasted it like week ago, should I repaste it again if I remove the heat pipe?

Paste must be reapplied every time the surfaces the paste is between are separated.
